# explicit conversion operator vs get< T >() function for std::variant

Tags: c++, variant, c++17, conversion-operator

What are the downsides to make a part of `std::variant` class an explicit conversion (to alternative) operator overloadings set in addition to (or even instead of) `get< T >()` free functions (p.568 of the [draft](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/n4606.pdf))?

```
template<class... Types>
class variant
{
    template<class T>
    explicit operator const T& () const&;
    template<class T>
    explicit operator T& () &;
    template<class T>
    explicit operator const T&& () const &&;
    template<class T>
    explicit operator T&& () &&;
};
```

Is it unsafe in some contexts? Why do we need free `get()` function (namely, "type" version, not "index" one), when variant exposes a value semantic (cite from the draft):

> A variant object holds and manages the lifetime of a value.

Isn't it enough to make a variant *explicitly* convertible to alternative, but still implicitly constructible from an alternative?

I know, the uniformity of the interface is good thing (I remember we need `get< I >()` along with `get< T >()`), but I think it is more natural way to get containing alternative value simply by converting to it, rather then applying some function specialization to variant instance.

Comment: For me, conversion implies "is a" relationship. get implies "has a" relationship ("what is this variant?" is a poorer question than "what does this variant contain?"). The more natural an interface maps to it's underlying abstractions, the better it is (IMO).

Comment: I don't see the contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

I can think of a few downsides:

- `std::variant` can hold *cv* `void`, but conversion functions returning *cv* `void&` and *cv* `void&&` would be illegal, and conversion functions to *cv* `void` are never called (**[class.conv.fct]**/1);
- It is possible for a `std::variant` to hold a type that can also be constructed from it, e.g.: `std::variant<std::monostate, std::any> v; std::any a{v};` - what should happen in this case?

In addition, currently it is possible to take a function returning `T`, convert it to a function returning `std::variant<T, U>` and expect the compiler to detect all cases where code needs to be changed; with a conversion function to `T` any cases where code was copying or binding a reference to `T` would result in a bug:

```
int f();
int i{f()};    // OK

// f() changes to:
std::variant<int, std::string> f();
int i{f()};    // can now throw std::bad_variant_access
```

Comment: Is `get< void >()` well-formed? BTW can't understand last sentence. May you decompose it?

Comment: @Orient no, but that's OK until you actually attempt to call it. Conversion operators to reference to *cv* `void` would have to be explicitly excluded from generation, and then you might think that you'd called them when actually a conversion to rvalue `void` is a no-op.

Comment: Oh, you meant `(void)v`/`static_cast< void >(v)`/`void(v)`. BTW it has corresponding warning in modern compilers ("unused member function"). Anyways, there would be a set of *cv-ref-qualified* overloadings of conversion operators, returning similarly *cv-ref-qualified* underlying values (for example `operator const T& () const &`), and for `T == void` they will cause hard error during compilation and, hereby, requires special handling, as well as other (special) member functions (conversion c-tors and conversion assignment operators).

Comment: Sure, the variant should be (explicitly) converted to one of the cases of the variant, not to arbitrary types. So the cases of `any` can be handled. The case case of `void` is more tricky but it can be taken as `monostate` for all purposes.

Answer (score 1):

1) I think there is one case that is *uncontroversial*, if the `std::variant` has only one case. (This can happen in generic code.) Then the variant should be (implicitly, IMO) convertible to that single type.

```
std::variant<double> v(5.3);
...
double d; d = v; // should be ok
```

2) For the other non-degenerate cases, I think it should be convertible (explicitly) just as `std::get` would do. 
I would do it only for the cases of the *original* `variant` (and not to arbitrary types.)

```
std::variant<double, int> v(5.3);
...
double d{v}; // should be ok, but can throw
```

I don't think the excuses for not having the feature because of the `void` case are good.
At worst, `void` is the problem, not `variant`. 
`void` cases should be handled by `monostate` (or in the future by "regular `void`").

So in summary I support your idea, except that I would put restriction on the conversion operators.

<s>Also, I would return a copy and not a reference (definitely not a non-constant reference). 
The reason is that with a reference one could put the variant content in an invalid state (as would happen with raw unions) or the reference itself can be in an invalid state if the variant changes case later.</s>

[EDIT: I take that back, references are invalidated all the time and that is ok, for example if you take a reference to an element of a vector and the vector is resized later.]

```
template<class... Types>
class variant
{
    template<class T>
    explicit operator T&() const{return std::get<T>(*this);}
    ...
};

template<class T>
class variant
{
    /*implicit*/ operator T&() const{return std::get<T>(*this);}
    ...
};
```

---

**Some temporary workarounds given the lack of the feature,**

a. Derived from `std::variant` and add these functions. Deriving or agregating from variant seems to be a common pattern.

b. Overload functions for the variant case so it can take variants directly and immediately call the original function over `std::get<type>(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

My main reason not to propose it was the following:

- optional doesn't have it
- optional has an `explicit operator bool()` (`has_value()` or not?)
- variant and optional should remain as consistent as possible.

But given the right arguments this could certainly be changed in a future revision.